# How to deal with the Package lipsum Package expl3 too old error without losing my work?

Tags: errors, packages, expl3, update

I was compiling a template and I got this error:

```
! Package lipsum Package expl3 too old.
```

so I was wondering if there is a way to update the `expl3` package but without losing my previous work, since my whole packages are old but they work perfectly with my code and I didn't update my whole packages, and I am working on my thesis so I am afraid I would lose everything if I changed anything.

Comment: There are several ways to update packages, depending on how you installed LaTeX. Which operating system do you use? Windows with MikTeX? Linux with TeX Live? MacOS with MacTeX, or MacOS with TeX Live? If you have some flavor of TeX Live, do you use `tlmgr` as package manager or not? Generally updating packages does not break your document, there might be cases that your old code does not work anymore with newer packages. However you don't need to be afraid that your document itself will be lost, this never happens (but make a backup just in case).

Comment: i use Windows with MikTeX , and as you mentioned the old code might not work with newer packages and that's exactly my fear since i need to submit my thesis real soon .

Comment: Why do you need lipsum in your thesis?

Comment: i was looking for a decorated page for dedication and acknowledgement and all the examples i found use this package

Comment: @lily no real document should use lipsum, it is a package for making _nonsense_ text to pad out _examples_ of package use.

Comment: As David mentioned, the `lipsum` package is most probably not necessary for the decorated pages, it is just to provide example text. So once you put 'real' text in your dedication page you can remove `\usepackage{lipsum}`. If you do want to update `expl3` without affecting your current setup then you can compile a version of the package locally, which is unfortunately a bit involved because the package is very complex and uses a custom installation mechanism.

Comment: The easiest would be to just update everything in MiKTeX and solve any problems that you might encounter with your document - that will probably be easier than you think, and if not, the site is here to provide assistance :)

Comment: No, you can use the decorated pages, just without `lipsum`.

Comment: okey thank you i will try to do that

Comment: @KJO   thank you for the advice , actually i always  keep  backups on Dropbox and  other drives in case i lost my pc  or it stopped working

Comment: Did updating fix your problem?